# KeyListener does not work when exported as a runnable jar file

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, keyevent

So here's the deal. I'm using eclipse to code a primitive looking space flight. When the user presses space, it changes to a different JPanel that does a different animation, and then when pressing space again it returns to the first JPanel. When I run it out of eclipse there are no problems, and it runs flawlessly. When I then export it as a runnable jar, and then run it, pressing space does nothing. It seems like it doesn't pick me pressing the space bar up at all.

```
package com;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Runner implements KeyListener {
    int framerate = 60;
    int WIDTH,HEIGHT;
    boolean state;
    int amountOfPlanets = 1000;
    Planet[] Planets;
    Window window;
    JPanel travel,zoom,display;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Runner();
    }
    public Runner() {
        state = true;
        HEIGHT = 1080; WIDTH = 1920;
        window = new Window(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        Planets = new Planet[amountOfPlanets];
        for (int i = 0; i < Planets.length; i++) {
            Planets[i] = new Planet(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        }
        travel = new Panel(Planets,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        window.add(travel);  
        window.addKeyListener(this);
        run();
    }
    public void run() {
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        while (thread != null) {

            update();
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000/framerate);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
    public void update() {
        if (state)
            ((Panel) travel).movePlanets();
        else {
            if (!((moveToPlanet) zoom).finished()) {
                ((moveToPlanet) zoom).movePlanets();
            }
        }
    }
    public void repaint() {
        if (state)
            travel.repaint();
        else
            zoom.repaint();
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
        if (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            if (state)
                goToPlanet();
            else 
                leavePlanet();
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
    }
    public void goToPlanet() {
        Planet[] temp = ((Panel) travel).getPlanets();
        zoom = new moveToPlanet(temp,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        temp = null;
        window.remove(travel);
        window.add(zoom);
        window.revalidate();
        state=!state;
    }
    public void leavePlanet() {
        Planet[] temp = ((moveToPlanet) zoom).getPlanets();
        temp[((moveToPlanet) zoom).p] = new Planet(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        travel = new Panel(temp,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        temp = null;
        window.remove(zoom);
        window.add(travel);
        window.revalidate();
        state=!state;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) `window.remove(travel);
        window.add(zoom);
        window.revalidate(); ..` Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: An [mcve] would be better as this would give us code that we could test ourselves, and removes you having to guess if the posted code is in fact the code causing the problem.

Comment: `KeyListener` is a poor choice and is will known for it's issues, related to focus.  Instead, use the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will solve the issue.

Comment: You're also not using the `Thread` properly.  I would recommend using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead, as it doesn't violate the single threaded rules of Swing, risking dirty reads